# Can't update cabal in Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos

I am trying to install cabal (for Haskell) in Mac OS X 10.6.5 (64-bit kernel). When I try the command "cabal update" I am presented with the following error:

```
cabal: Codec.Compression.Zlib: premature end of compressed stream
```

Does anyone have experience with this and knows how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently:

> This bug disappears if you compile cabal-install with GHC 6.12.1. ([here](http://osdir.com/ml/cabal-devel@haskell.org/2010-03/msg00009.html) and [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/636))